# Google Maps Coordinate android

Tags: android, google-maps, coordinate-systems

I want to use google map coordinate in my android application.
http://www.google.com/intl/en/enterprise/mapsearth/products/coordinate.html?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=NA-LCS-2013-Geo-Products-MapsCoordinate-HouseAds&utm_term=%2Bgoogle%20%2Bcoordinate&utm_content=SearchAd&gclid=COy759vU2LsCFVMdtAodNGYAdg

I found this example on google play: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.geo.enterprise.flak

I searched on internet but didn't find documentation about how to implement google coordinate in my anndoid app.
Did any one used this before? If yes can you please put links of tutorial or links of samples?

Comment: Did you try this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Comment: that's a sample mapview, i want a google mapview + google coordinate

Comment: i found this documentation link: https://developers.google.com/coordinate/
But still not enough clear. Is there a demo or a sample app?

Comment: @haythemsouissi the documentation you linked has the following sample: https://code.google.com/p/coordinate-ticketing/

Comment: this is not an android sample, this is phyton. Is there an android sample?

Answer (score 0):

Try this link, to the [Google Maps Coordinate API Client Library for Java](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/coordinate/v1).

Otherwise, if you want to start from scratch, it's a RESTful api.  There are a number of clients and  libraries that you could use, including Volley.  Also, here is a [tutorial for making remote calls](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-making-remote-api-calls/).

Answer (score 0):

You can find everything you need [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intro).

I have done it following this official tutorial recently. The version 2 of Google Maps Android API is different from version 1 in many points.

Comment: there are many maps examples here, but no one show how to use google map coordinate